# Click button, add data to SQL and click again to remove data, Need php code

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, button

In the post list page I made, I added a favorite button to Javascript. But I can't use it as a favorite button. I want, when I click on the button, a value will be added to my database as the button becomes red. And clicking again will remove the value.

[The JavaScript button I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pPUs.jpg)

[My table name tbl_post and attribute name fav_button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq9Ub.jpg)

my code postlist.php

```
<div class="block">
        <table class="data display datatable" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">No.</th>
                    <th width="15%">Post Title</th>
                    <th class="list-post" width="14%">Description</th>

                    <th width="12%">Category</th>
                    <th width="10%">Image</th>

                    <th width="12%">Tags</th>

                    <th width="12%">Date</th>

                    <th width="10%">Front</th>

                    <th width="10%">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT tbl_post. *, tbl_category.name FROM tbl_post
            INNER JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_post.cat = tbl_category.id
            ORDER BY date ";
            $post =  $db->select($query);

            if ($post) {
                $i = 0;
                while ($result = $post->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $i++; ?>

                        <tr class="odd gradeX  mng2">
                            <td class="mng"><?php echo $i; ?>|</td>
                            <td class="mng"><?php echo $result['title']; ?></td>

                            <td class="mng list-post" id="a"><?php echo $fm->textShorten($fm->wp_strip_all_tags($result['body']), 50); ?></td>

                            <td class="mng dt"><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>

                            <td class="mng"><img class="img_db" src="<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" /></td>

                            <td class="mng"><?php echo $result['tags']; ?></td>

                            <td class="mng dt"><?php echo $fm->postListdate($result['date']) ?></td>

                        <!-- fav button add ---->

                            <td class="mng dt">

                            <div class="flexbox">

                                <div class="fav-btn">
                                    <span href="" class="favme dashicons dashicons-heart"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            </td>


                            <td class="mng">
                                <a class="dif_2" href="./edit-post.php?editpostid=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> ||
                                <a onclick="return confirm('Im Sure to DELETE?')
                                " class="dif_1" href="./del-post.php?delpostid=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                <?php
                    }
                } ?>


        </table>

    </div>
```

```js
$('.favme').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".favme").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});


$(".favme").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});
```

```css
 .flexbox {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
 .fav-btn {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
 @keyframes favme-anime {
  0% {
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: ms(0);
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
 }
  25% {
   opacity: 0.6;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: ms(-2);
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #dc3232;
 }
  75% {
   opacity: 0.6;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: ms(3);
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #dc3232;
 }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: ms(2);
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
 }
}
 @keyframes favme-hover {
  from {
   font-size: ms(3);
 }
  80% {
   font-size: ms(2);
 }
}
 .favme {
  display: block;
  font-size: ms(2);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  color: #cbcdce;
  margin: 0;
}
 .favme.active {
  color: #dc3232;
}
 .favme:hover {
  animation: favme-hover 0.3s infinite alternate;
}
 .favme.is_animating {
  animation: favme-anime 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">




<div class="flexbox">

         <div class="fav-btn">
          <span href="" class="favme dashicons dashicons-heart"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
         </div>
         
        </div>
```

Comment: Which is you problem?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code writing service. You need to start writing this on your own - we can help you if you run into problems with that, but then you need to show us what you tried and give us a proper problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small script.

```js
/*using ajax*/

$('#fav').click(function() {
   $e = $(this);
   $status =  $e.data('status');
   $id =  $e.data('id');
  $operation = ($status)?'add':'remove';
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/addtofav",
    cache: false,
    data:{'id':$id,'operation':$operation},
    success: function(data){
       if($status){
        $e.addClass('nonfavpro')
        $e.removeClass('favpro')
        $e.data('status',false)
       }else{
        $e.addClass('favpro')
        $e.removeClass('nonfavpro')
        $e.data('status',true)
       }
    }
   });
});

/*Without ajax simple change property of button*/
$('#fav1').click(function() {
   $e = $(this);
   $status =  $e.data('status');
    if($status){
        $e.addClass('nonfavpro')
        $e.removeClass('favpro')
        $e.data('status',false)
       }else{
        $e.addClass('favpro')
        $e.removeClass('nonfavpro')
        $e.data('status',true)
       }
       
});
```

```css
.favpro{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nonfavpro{
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
**using-Ajax**
<button id="fav" data-id="1" data-status="false" class="nonfavpro">Add to fav</button>

**Non-Ajax**
<button id="fav1" data-status="false" class="nonfavpro">Add to fav</button>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I need to php code,  Click to button, add data to SQL and click again to remove data

Comment: if you need a javascript button with PHP code. you need to use the `ajax` option. which I already put in code